# Encontrar los sueldos mas altos de cada departamento?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas (employee, department), dentro de las cuales que mostrar:

- Departamento
- Nombre de empleado
- Salario

De los salarios mas altos ( si n trabajadores tienen el mismo sueldo, tengo que mostrarlos ). Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto ejemplos que usan TOP 3 o DESC LIMIT 3 pero no he tenido resultado o no he podido aplicarlo bien. Este es el query que tengo hasta ahorita:

```
select d.name as "Department", e.name as "Employee", max(e.salary) as "Salary" from employee e join department as d on e.department = d.id group by e.department
```

Estructura de employee:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura de department:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Listo, lo acabo de agregar!

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te están pidiendo es algo así:

```
SELECT department,`name`,salary FROM (
    SELECT department,MAX(salary) salary
      FROM employee
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN employee USING(salary,department);
```

En primer lugar obtienes los salarios máximos de cada departamento y, después, combinas por departamento y salario.

```
SELECT d.department,`name`,salary FROM (
    SELECT department,`name`,salary FROM (
        SELECT department,MAX(salary) salary
          FROM employee
          GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1 JOIN employee USING(salary,department)
  ) c2 JOIN department d ON d.id=c2.department;
```

El último `JOIN` es para mostrar el nombre del departamento en vez su `id`.

Como tú lo planteas no es posible, pues debes decidir entre detalle o totales. Únicamente puedes mostrar un total por cada grupo. La pregunta está muy bien planteada para ilustrar este concepto.

Aporto el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  department varchar(31)
  );

CREATE TABLE employee(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(31),
  salary float,
  department int,
  FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(id)
  );
```

Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios.